# Is there anything I can do to attract spiders in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really need to kill some spiders so I can make a bow and fishing rod, but there are no spiders to be seen in my vicinity.

Is there a technique I can use to either attract them to a known location or discover where they are?

I'm playing on easy/normal so the mobs do spawn - I've seen creepers and zombies but no spiders.

Comment: actually, i have the impression that spiders only show up on the 3rd or 4th day since you begin a new game. i never studied it very carefully, though. (you can still be on the first few days)

Comment: @JoséNunoFerreira > The first enemy I ever encountered was a Spider, within minutes of starting my first world.

Comment: I'd say that spiders like sand a lot.When I am on sand,there is usually spiders. =)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee mob spawns of a particular type unless you happen to find a mob spawner.  Your best bet is to simply set up a situation that allows a lot of enemies to spawn and then weed out the spiders.

There are a variety of traps that can be set up, [from very simple to very complex](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=minecraft+mob+trap&aq=f).  One of the easiest ways to get a lot of enemies to spawn, however, is to simply set up a tower in an open area (keeping you safe and able to see a large distance).

Spiders have three attributes that you can abuse to catch them:

- They are 2 blocks wide by 1 block high.  All other enemies are taller than they are wide, so a 2x1 hole will allow spiders through while keeping you safe from other enemies.  This can allow you to deal with them specifically if you want to build some sort of trap room.
- Spiders do not die from sunlight.  This is why the tower tends to work well - even if a lot of monsters spawn nearby, you can wait for sunrise and then you will only have to watch out for creepers while you take down whatever spiders have spawned.  As an added bonus, *spiders will not be hostile during the day* until you attack (or if they were already after you from nighttime).
- Spiders can climb walls (but a lip will stop them). A platform, at least two blocks high and well lit, can help you separate the spiders from other monsters, as only they will be able to climb up after you.

Comment: After starting to build such a tower I coincidentally came across some spiders so now have a bow! Still need to finish it off and see if I can attract some more.

Comment: Sure.  You'll need a fishing rod too, right?

Comment: As it turned out I've come across more spiders "in the wild" and got enough silk for a fishing rod too. The creeper that came after it did blow half my house away though :(

Comment: Spiders can now climb walls! So take that into account when constructing towers. An outward-facing lip is the easiest way to prevent them from climbing up.

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse the Minecraft spawning physics to make a spider spawner. You see, all other hostile mobs (except maybe slimes, which only spawn at the bottom of the map anyway) require a 2 blocks high space to spawn in. However, spiders require a slightly different shape, a 3x3 square, but only one block high. So, if you want to spawn spiders, your best bet would be to make a two squares, one on top of the other, with a block of empty space between them. Due to the low height, only spiders will be able to spawn on the lower square, and because of the darkness (if you wall off the edges or make it large), they'll be the only ones to spawn there. You can then remove pieces of the top (when it's light out, so they'll be non-agressive), kill the spiders, and collect the string. (Obviously this would be impractical if you needed to reuse the device often, but since string is only really needed for bows/fishing rods, you don't need more than a handful of spiders)

Comment: Actually, spiders need a 3x3 square but *still* need two blocks of height to spawn. There are "no spider" mob grinders that depend on this behaviour.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You can actually use a 3x3x1 space [according to the wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Spider#Spawning_Criteria), as long as the ceiling is glass or another non-transparent block. 

Based on this, you could cover a large flat area with repeated layers of air/glass/cobblestone (air for spawn space, glass to permit spawn, and cobblestone to spawn on) and make a multi-tier spawn area.

Comment: @Doktor J -- that should say "transparent block", not "non-transparent block" >_<

Comment: @Doktor J Oh, *that* is a nifty distinction. That makes for very flexible mob trap designs!